# embedded C++: how to prevent call to std::ios_base::init

Tags: c++, g++

I write embbeded (bare metal) C++ code. I don't use any iostream features, I don't include any such headers. I use the very latest gcc 10.1 ARM cross compiler (https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/x86_64/arm-none-eabi-gcc). When I compile main(), the compiler inserts an initialization of std::ios_base::init. This did not happen with any of the earlier creoss compilers I used. Is there a way to prevent the compiler from inserting this initialization call? (I already use -nostdlib).

Comment: Does a simple empty app like `int main() { return 42; }` do this? Can you show us on https://godbolt.org?

Comment: AAAAAARG my error. I though I had no iostream includes anywhere but there was one. Thanks! - Now I can start struggling with the deprecated uses of volatile, which seem to include for ( ; ; ++i), but NOT for( ; ; ++1, (void)1 )